# How to format a string into a two column list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a python string in the following format:

```
"x1 y1\n x2 y2\n x3 y3\n ..."
```

I would like to transform this into a list `points = [p1, p2, p3,...]`, where `p1`, `p2` and `p3` are `[x1,y1]`, `[x2,y2]` and `[x3,y3]` etc.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to provide your code attempts so we have a place to start?

Comment: for now my code is to read in the ouput from a bash command. the command is : rbox 100 D2, this produces the coordinates of 100 random points. now i'm stuck in formatting these ouputs. i use python subprocess to get the ouput

Comment: Then this might be a good place to start learning about string operations such as parsing: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think you can use the following:

```
inputText = "x1 y1\n x2 y2\n x3 y3\n"
print [line.split() for line in inputText.split('\n') if line]
```

Comment: oh, so you seem to have beaten me to this... by 3mins. +1

Answer (score 2):

obviously, many ways to do this.

I would use list comprehension for its brevitiy.

```
>>> str = 'x1 y1\n x2 y2\n x3 y3\n'
>>> [p.split() for p in str.split('\n') if p != ''] 
[['x1', 'y1'], ['x2', 'y2'], ['x3', 'y3']]
```

Comment: i'm totally overwhelmed by the quality and speed of the answers from stackoverflow... Thanks everyone

Comment: hah, yeah, I never do. but I'm not to creative when answering questions sometimes. I was trying to make this as logical and concise as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
points = []
for point in myStr.split('\n'):
    points.append(point.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a='x1 y1\n x2 y2\n x3 y3\n'

points = map (lambda x : x.split (), a.split ('\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this do?

```
>>> raw = "x1 y1\nx2 y2\nx3 y3"
>>> lines = raw.split("\n")
>>> points = []
>>> for l in lines:
...     points.append(l.split(' '))
... 
>>> points
[['x1', 'y1'], ['x2', 'y2'], ['x3', 'y3']]
>>>
```

Split on new lines, then for each line assume a space splits the values, create a list of points from that.